# Docker: files missing after build

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to build a docker container that runs a Python script. I want the code to be cloned from git when I build the image. I'm using [this](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/6a8869e8a4e90d6ae4ca3569d1f7dbb867c9ad74/3.9-rc/buster/slim/Dockerfile) docker file as a base and added the following BEFORE the first line:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim AS intermediate

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan [git hostname] >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone git@...../myApp.git
```

... then added the following directly after the first line:

```
# Copy only the repo from the intermediate image
COPY --from=intermediate /myApp /myApp
```

... then at the end I added this to install some dependencies:

```
RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y gcc g++ unixodbc-dev libpq-dev; \
    \
    pip install pyodbc; \
    pip install paramiko; \
    pip install psycopg2
```

And I changed the command to run to:

```
CMD ["python3 /myApp/main.py"]
```

If, at the end of the dockerfile before the CMD, I add the command "RUN ls -l /myApp" it lists all the files I would expect during the build. But when I use "docker run" to run the image, it gives me the following error:

**docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "python3 /myApp/main.py": stat python3 /myApp/main.py: no such file or directory": unknown.**

My build command is:
`docker build --file ./Dockerfile --tag my_app --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat sshkey)" .`

Then run with `docker run my_app`

There is probably some docker fundamental that I am misunderstanding, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer without your command line or your docker-compose.yml (if any). A recurrent mistake is to map a volume from the host into the container at a non empty location, in this case, your container files are hidden by the content of the host folder.

The last CMD should be like this:

```
CMD ["python3", "/myApp/main.py"]
```

Comment: The CMD change actually fixed it. Thanks so much.

Comment: What you currently have would be equivalent to running `'python3 ./main.py'` on a host checkout, _with the single quotes_ – it forces the command and its argument into a single "word", where you need it to be two separate words.

Comment: That explains the ```stat python3 /myApp/main.py``` in the error message. That should've tipped me off in hindsight.